# How do I get the user's neighborhood or city from $user.currentLocation?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm wondering if maybe some one can help me figure this out. How do I get the user's neighborhood (or city) from $user.currentLocation?

I've been trying various things, and looked at the docs, especially here:
https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.geo#searchregion-and-currentlocation
But it's not quite what I'm looking for.

If the user says, "What's the weather?" without specifying the place, my getWeather action looks like this:

```
input (where) {
      min (Optional) max(One)
      type (viv.geo.NamedPoint)
      default-select {
        with-rule {
          select-first
        }
      }
       default-init {
         if ($user.currentLocation.$exists) {
           intent {
             goal: geo.GeoPoint
             value-set: geo.CurrentLocation { $expr ($user.currentLocation) }
           }
         } 
       }
```

This will give me the long/lat that I use for the weather API query. But I'd like to display (though not say) the neighborhood (or city) of the users current location in a view.
(I believe if I change the goal/value-set to SearchRegion, then I can get the city, but not the long/lat of $user.currentLocation. Instead, I get a generic  long/lat of the city, which isn't specific enough.)

So, I want 1) The long/lat of $user.currentLocation for the API and 2) the neighborhood (or city) of that long/lat for a view. I can't figure out how to get both.

Answer (score 0):

The input you've defined is a `NamedPoint` and `NamedPoint.point` is a `GeoPoint` so it should have the lat/longs you need.

To get the city, the `NamedPoint.address` should contain an `Address` structure to access the Street address, city, state, country, etc.

Another option might be the `reverseGeo` property of a `GeoPoint` to get the Address. This property is a `lazy-source` so the data will not be available until this property is called.